# Preprocess OSM streets to see if query points fall "on" them

Tags: postgis, intersection, osm2pgsql

I am interested in the following query:

*Given a set of query points ($\leq 10$), how many of them have distance at most $s$ meters to the closest point on the closest street.*

What's the most efficient way of writing / pre-processing this query?

1) Pre-process the roads (in osm2pgsql) by replacing each road by a Buffer of $s$ meter width. Then do stabbing queries using `ST_Contains`.

2) Replace each query point by a circle of radius $s$ and query if any road is intersected by a query circle.

3) Other Approaches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your questions it seems to be a pretty easy query:

> SELECT count(*) total FROM points INNER JOIN streets ON ST_DWithin(points.geom, streets.geom, maxdistance)

I would like to make use of your question to point out that option 2) is a bad idea since creating circles (aka buffers) is an [expensive and unnecessary](http://postgis.net/2013/08/26/tip_ST_DWithin/) task when you are only interested in a maximum distance. Option 1) is not needed but make sure you have spatial indices on your geometries so you automatically make use of the bounding boxes.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. Being new to databases I have a basic question: You join the points with the streets, but in my use case the points would be provided as user input to the query. Would that still work?

Comment: Yes, that would still work but the way you do it depends a bit on how many points each time and what kind of program interface you use. It would be best if you can phrase that in a new question, with a reference to this one. You can set this one to accepted for this case, if applicable.